# set Path as domain in vercel project setting

Tags: next.js, vercel

I have deployed one nextjs project on vercel
But I want to point to it using custom domain like
http://abctest.com/project
this domain should point to my vercel project

I can add **abctest.com** as domain but I can't add **abctest.com/project** as domain.
Can someone help me with adding path as domain in vercel

Comment: not sure I clearly got what you asking for, but have you tried adding `redirect` config in `vercel.json`?

Comment: @ogostos,
I have not tried it,
Let me explain more clearly
so https://example.com is a domain using by our client for their own website and we have to host one nextjs application on their website which should get open when someone hits
https://example.com/project